# Encryption method is failing on one PC but works on others

Tags: c#, encryption

I am having an issue where a file containing usernames and passwords is able to be decrypted on some machines but is failing on another.

The machine that it fails on is a brand new installation of Windows 7 embedded. All that has been installed is my application and .net service pack 4.6.2

I did not write this code originally but I need to get it working on the Win 7 embedded machines.

The error I am seeing is:

*UserManager error: Error reading C:\CutterBuild\Data\Config\users.xml :System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Key not valid for use in specified state.*

The relevant code is:

```
try
        {
            xmlDoc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
            xmlDoc.Load(inputFilePath);

            System.Security.Cryptography.CspParameters cspParams = new System.Security.Cryptography.CspParameters();
            cspParams.KeyContainerName = KEY_CONTAINER_NAME;

// Next line is Where the code fails and throws exception!!!!.
            System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaKey = new System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParams);
            EncryptionHelper.Decrypt(xmlDoc, rsaKey, KEY_NAME);

            reader = new XmlNodeReader(xmlDoc);
            collection = Read(reader, out errorMessage);
        }
```

I did some debugging and everything looks good up to the rsa key point. The Microsoft documentation on the error is no help.

I did some reading on this and found it confusing, It states in the documentation that you need to create a security certificate, but I can't find any instructions on how to do this. And shouldn't it be created on one machine and copied to others? Where does it get copied to? I can't find anything about it on my PC, but the decrypt is working fine on my PC.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: When you say it's working on "others" (plural) do you mean just your machine or does it really work on multiple other machines?

Comment: Seems a lot like the issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41952632/cryptographicexception-key-not-valid-for-use-in-specified-state

Comment: First, this sounds like digital signature, not encryption (unless these are very small files). Asymmetric cryptography is limited to the block size of the encryption minus a few bytes of overhead (less than 256 bytes for RSA). Second, any computer that needs to decrypt must have the public key cert of the computer that encrypted installed. Normally for files, RSA is used to encrypt symmetric keys and a symmetric algorithm (using those symmetric keys) is used to encrypt the bulk of the file.

Comment: I checked all of the machines we have that are working. all of them contained a file in the C:\Users\ttalma\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA folder that started with the same string of chars but ended with different ones, and itsme86 linked to. The machine that didn't work, had an empty folder. How do I create this file for the mamchine with the missing file?